# uitableview reloadData - how do we table refresh is done?

Tags: uitableview

I want to do a reloadData on a UITableView and after the table refresh is done, I want a delegate method to be called when I can know that the refresh is done. How do we know that ?

Answer (score 1):

`-reloadData` blocks execution—your code won't continue past that call unless you're doing it on a separate thread. It should only be configuring nine cells or so at most; is there some reason you expect that to take a long time?

Comment: Well, because when the table is down refreshing I would have like to scroll at a specific row... but now I'm doing this with a performInBackground after delay of 1 sec which more than enough for the table to be redrawn.

Comment: This isn't quite what I experience. Specifically, I find that the various height method (e.g. `heightForRowAtIndexPath`) are called before `reloadData` returns, but other methods, such as `cellForRowAtIndexPath` are not called until after `reloadData` returns. So I guess it depends upon what you mean by "know that the refresh is done."